# Whether use TCP or UDP for video streaming on local network?

Tags: android, sockets, network-programming, udp

I need some suggestion here. Do you think UDP is a better choice for sending the files from one pc to another or say from one device to another like iphone, android etc?

regards

Answer (score 4):

Your question title says "video streaming", for which UDP is an appropriate choice.  UDP does not guarantee packet delivery, but this doesn't really matter for video streaming.

The body of your question, however, says "sending files", which isn't exactly the same as streaming.  If you're trying to transfer whole files from one device to another (and it's important that the entire file makes a successful transfer), then TCP is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to stream real time Live video. Now is UDP a better option to stream video from one machine to another or Tcp. Secondly how to compare RTSP for that. I mean I need some clear picture of the two approaches. Because if I am using TCP/UDP then I would be actually sending the stream frame by frame I suppose and if I go for RTSP then I will have to expose the link for that to be used by the different Machines. Kindly throw some light on the approaches.

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to intepret.

In the title, you talk about "streaming", but in the body you say "files".

Streaming is best done using UDP, since TCP always delivers data in order: if a packet is lost and must be re-send, the application won't get any data until TCP has solved it. For real-time data, this is undesirable.

Files are better sent using TCP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thing I mentioned files wrong in the description. I want to stream real time Live video. Now is UDP a better option to stream video from one machine to another or Tcp. Secondly how to compare RTSP for that. I mean I need some clear picture of the approach.

Answer (score 1):

Start to look at UDP when you wish to send to multiple recipients and the cost of throwing multiple boxes at the problem becomes excessive.

So assess the situation, the development cost of a UDP transport is higher to significantly higher than TCP and to some degree you are re-inventing TCP.  The benefit of multicast is obvious, but what benefits are there for unicast?  On modern hardware you have TCP acceleration which means UDP unicast is actually quite an expensive alternative.  The arguments of lower latency are for specific applications, i.e. gaming, and more importantly are linked to lack of reliability and low capped data rates.

NB: The initial performance differential developers see between TCP and UDP is [Nagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)'s and [TCP slow start](http://blog.benstrong.com/2010/11/google-and-microsoft-cheat-on-slow.html), i.e. congestion control, which is critical to scalability of inter-networks.  Both can be disable for internal network applications.

Comment: I'd imagine that the CPU cost of decoding and displaying the video data will be large enough that the CPU overhead of using UDP vs TCP will not be a significant factor.

Comment: @Jeremy You have acceleration for video decoding and display too, so the cost of everything is reduced such that you can run on cheaper platforms like ARM, Geode, when that happens the importance of network protocol becomes relevant again.